# Component-Based System online resources

Tags: architecture, entity-system, component-based

I've been considering moving to a more component-based approach in my games. Does anyone else have any decent reference material or sample implementations that would help make this transition a little easier?

Comment: I found some more links that may be useful to anyone coming back to this topic:
http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check out the links that I put in the bottom of [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/why-are-mvc-tdd-not-employed-more-in-game-architecture/3427#3427). A good number of them thoroughly answer this question, and I'd rather not duplicate the information here.

In particular, there is a question, ["Component based game engine design"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901251/component-based-game-engine-design) which I think directly answers your question.

Comment: great stuff! FRP sounds interesting, never heard of that before. Probably a fancy name for something I've been using before but not knowing that people decided to call it FRP. :)

Answer (score 8):

Game objects as sets of components:

http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/
http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html

Game engine as a set of components independently working with shared Data Storage:

http://www.acims.arizona.edu/PUBLICATIONS/PDF/JeffPlummerMSthesis_wo_Appendix.pdf

Comment: The first two links are fantastic! However, that thesis is a little rough with all the "deadwood" text. It's just not in a form that I can view as helpful to its content.